# Mapping a word to its synonyms in java application

Tags: java, jdbc

I am working on a word-synonyms application but am having a challenge. The challenge/question is how do i map a word and its synonyms in my application database?

Comment: A tree structure of some kind where words keep references to their synonyms would be my suggestion, as there are many cross-references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synonyms are *commutative* but not *transitive*.

I cannot find an example, so the following artificial one:

```
bank
synonym(bank) = money-institute   => synonym(money-institute) = bank
synonym(bank) = place-to-sit      => synonym(money-institute) = bank

place-to-sit:
synonym(place-to-sit) = bank
synonym(place-to-sit) = chair

NOT synonym(chair) = money-institute
```

This means that you need only a list of pairs without order, and both one is the synonym of the other and vice versa. And more you need not do.

```
public class SynonymTable {

private Map<Word, Set<Word>> synonymTable = new HashMap<>();

public Set<Word> getSynonyms(Word word) {
    return synonymTable.get(word);
}

public void registerSynonym(Word word, Word... synonymsOfWord) {
    for (Word syn : synonymsOfWord) {
        putSynonymTable(word, syn); // synonym(word) = syn
        putSynonymTable(syn, word); // synonym(syn) = word
    }
}

private void putSynonymTable(Word word, Word synonymOfWord) {
    Set syns = synonymTable.get(word);
    if (syns == null) {
        syns = new TreeSet<Word>();
        synonymTable.put(word, syns);
    }
    syns.add(synonymOfWord);
}
...
```

---

***Database variant***

```
CREATE TABLE TWord (
    wordId INT AUTO_INCR,
    wordText VARCHAR(80),
    INDEX(wordText),
    PRIMARY KEY(wordId)
);
CREATE TABLE TSynonym (
    wordFk INT NOT NULL,
    synonymFk INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (wordFk) REFERENCES TWord(wordId),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (synonymFk) REFERENCES TWord(wordId),
    PRIMARY KEY(wordFk, synonymFk)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for elaborating your answer, but i dont understand 'commutative' not 'transitive' in this context. If i get your answer very well, are you trying to say that i don't/can't use a database to store words and its synonyms mapped?

Comment: A database is fine, even appropiate. I misused thhe math terms commutative/transitive, thought that would clearify the case. My point: _if A has synonym of B and C, then both B and C have a synonym A. But B and C not necessarily are synonyms._

Comment: But what do mean by using word in your parameter lists like in your methods registerSynonym, putSynonymTable, getSynonyms? Do i use string objects there? And another thing is after having this class , so how do i structure my  database to keep the word and its synonyms so that when the word is called it returns the synonyms?

Comment: `Word` is an on-the-fly abstraction, using `String` will do.

Comment: using jdbc which one do i insert into the database, the getSynonyms(String word) and the word. as in something like this Statement st = con.createStatement();  st.executeUpdate("insert into tablename values (word, getSynonyms(word)");

Comment: There is an error in this part of the code, i have tried resolving it. but i end up messing the whole code. may be you can help me.                                                                                                              public void registerSynonym(Word word, Word... synonymsOfWord) {
    for (Word syn : synonymsOfWord) {
        putSynonymTable(synonymTable(word, syn); // synonym(word) = syn
        putSynonymTable(synonymTable(syn, word); // synonym(syn) = word
        synonymTable.put(syn, word);
    }
}

Comment: @GreenOnyeji, corrected code; actually removed writing garbage.

Comment: Concerning database: one would insert in TSynonym both: if A and B are synonyms (A, B) and (B, A).

Answer (score 1):

Use a map, something like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> synonyms;
```

In the above, the key to the map will be the word and the corresponding value will be a list of synonyms.

In terms of databases, create a table with synonym words and a table with words, each word in the synonyms table will hold a foreign key reference to the word. This can be easily mapped to the above data structure.

Comment: Or perhaps better `Map<String, Set<String>>`.

Comment: @oscar, how then can i store a map variable in the database. Can you give me a clue on how the code is going to look like?

Comment: @GreenOnyeji using jdbc you have no choice but to do it manually - traverse the keys in the map, for each key traverse the associated list and then persist them accordingly - each element in the list is a row in the synonyms table, with the key as foreign key

Answer (score 0):

If your application as simple as described in the question, then as suggested in other answer Map with a Set or list value is sufficient. If you are comfortable with third party libraries, you may check [Guava's Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). As per the documentation:

> A collection similar to a Map, but which may associate multiple values
>   with a single key. If you call put(K, V) twice, with the same key but
>   different values, the multimap contains mappings from the key to both
>   values.